# Should I store the result of an function into an array?

Tags: php, performance, function

I have a function like this:

```
function time_elapsed_string($ptime)
{
            $date_time = strtotime("1348-10-10 04:30:01") + $ptime;
            $year = date("Y",$date_time);
            $month = date("m",$date_time);
            $day = date("d",$date_time);
            $time = date("H:i:s",$date_time);

    $etime = time() - $ptime + 1;

    $a = array( 31536000  =>  'year',
                 2592000  =>  'month',
                   86400  =>  'day',
                    3600  =>  'hour',
                      60  =>  'minute',
                       1  =>  'second'
                );

    foreach ($a as $secs => $str)
    {
        $d = $etime / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1)
        {
            $r = round($d);
                                                                   // EX:
            return array('date' => $day.'-'.$month.'-'.$year,      // 2016-02-20
                         'time' => $time,                          // 03:30:04
                         'difference' => $r . ' ' . $str . ' ago'  // 2 month ago
                        );
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
$ptime = 1470692661;
$html = '<span title="date: '.time_elapsed_string($ptime)['date'].' time: '.time_elapsed_string($ptime)['time'].'">in '.time_elapsed_string($ptime)['difference'].'<span>';
```

As you see, I'm using of that function's result like this:

```
time_elapsed_string($ptime)['date']
ime_elapsed_string($ptime)['time']
time_elapsed_string($ptime)['difference']
```

In fact I'm calling that function every time I need one of its results. Is that right? Or should I call it once and store it into an array?

**Note:** My code works as well.

Comment: what are you using it for?

Comment: @Nordenheim To make something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/UDjj2.png

Comment: your underlying assumptions about 'time' are wrong. you should use http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counting time elapsed since some date/time like this is *mauvais ton*.

[`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) has been available since PHP 5.2.0 and tonns of people underestimate it. Why don't you use this instead of `loop`s and `if`s?

```
$create_time = "2016-08-02 12:35:04";
$current_time="2016-08-02 16:16:02";

$dtCurrent = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_time);
// to use current timestamp, use the following:
//$dtCurrent = new DateTime();
$dtCreate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $create_time);
$diff = $dtCurrent->diff($dtCreate);
```

Now, you can [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) the result however you want:

```
$interval = $diff->format("%h hours %i minutes %s seconds");
```

This will give a clean `3 hours 40 minutes 58 seconds` without any arrays, which is better.

**UPDATE**

There is a general solution to get hours / minutes / seconds via regex:

```
$interval = $diff->format("%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds");

// now remove zero values
$interval = preg_replace('/(^0| 0) (years|months|days|hours|minutes|seconds)/', '', $interval);
```

**UPDATE 2**

As of your comment:

> Look, I want to use your approach .. but I really cannot implement it .. Actually I need three things: `time`, `date`, `difference` ..! But your approach doesn't give me them..

Well, we already know how to get the difference, it's the `$interval` variable described above.

To get time and date, you can get it from the `$dtCreate` variable by, again, using format:

```
$time = $dtCreate->format('H:i:s');
$date = $dtCreate->format('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: strtotime\date should have large notes in the manual, to not actually use them

Comment: @Dagon they do, but in the end it's easier to lose array data than some object data, unless you explicitly call a setter or directly set them. IMO, objects should be used over arrays, because you can always restrict access to object properties.

Comment: Come on - regex - really? No need!

Comment: @RobbieAverill possibilities are endless from now on, however my point is not in using regex; it's in using `DateTime`

Comment: Look, I want to use your approach .. but I really cannot implement it .. Actually I need three things: `time`, `date`, `difference` ..! But [your approach](https://3v4l.org/5E8WI) doesn't give me them..

Comment: @MartinAJ I updated my answer. You should read the PHP manual, it's perfectly explained there.

Answer (score 4):

This is a no brainer.

**Yes** - store the function call result of `time_elapsed_string($ptime)` in an array, then use that to access your results. You're wasting CPU cycles otherwise!

```
// call it once
$result = time_elapsed_string($ptime);

// then use:
$result['date'];
$result['time'];
$result['difference'];
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. Just as a note, What's the meaning of *"This is a no brainer"*? (honestly I'm not good in English)

Comment: I wanna know cpu cycles are wasted acessing function multiple times and not wasted when accessing array multiple times

Comment: @MartinAJ  no brainer means : something that requires or involves little or no mental effort.