# How can I set something to the URL by PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, url

I want to set something to the URL when the page is loading ... How can I do that?

---

When you open this URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839016/should-i-store-the-result-of-an-function
```

automatically it will be replaced with this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839016/should-i-store-the-result-of-an-function-into-an-array
```

How does SO do that?

---

**Note:** I've disabled JavaScript on the browser, still that replacement happens. So it is done by PHP.

Comment: No, it's not done by PHP, Stack Overflow uses Microsoft software on their servers, not PHP. Even when using PHP, you'd probably have the server, i.e. Apache most of the time, do the redirect.

Comment: Read more about `.htaccess` and Permalinks.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ah .. Is replacing spaces with `-` is also done by `.htaccess`?

Comment: Thats a technique called **url rewriting in php** you can do this and any other way you want the url to be.. just read about how to do url rewritting resources

Comment: Just to verify, I don't think this site is running PHP at all. http://builtwith.com/stackoverflow.com

Comment: To [verify more correctly](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/), this site is running 4 Microsoft SQL Servers, 11 IIS Web Servers, 2 Redis Servers, 3 Tag Engine servers, 3 Elasticsearch servers, 4 HAProxy Load Balancers, 2 Networks (each a Nexus 5596 Core + 2232TM Fabric Extenders, upgraded to 10Gbps everywhere).
2 Fortinet 800C Firewalls (replaced Cisco 5525-X ASAs)
2 Cisco ASR-1001 Routers (replaced Cisco 3945 Routers)
2 Cisco ASR-1001-x Routers (new!)

Comment: @MartinAJ Yes buddy. The first answer explains everything... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple HTTP redirect. Each question has a slug. When the post slug doesn't match with the slug segment of the url, the HTTP controller redirects the page to the correct route.

Comment: Well I can do that redirect by PHP ..! Why not? BTW I don't know how HTTP access the title and how it can compare it with the real title...

Comment: That is correct (+1). The real identifier is the number `38839016`, the last part of the URL is "meaningless", in that *anything* will lead you to the correct question, with the correct "slug". The last part of the URL is mostly used for SEO and such things, and does not identify the question the URL links to

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427/why-do-some-websites-add-slugs-to-the-end-of-urls

Comment: @adeneo I see. Just one thing: that id `38839016` and that title are stored in the database.. So I **only** can do a *compare* and *redirect (it if is needed)* by PHP, not anything else like `.htaccess`. Right?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, it's your site, and your server. Of course you can create a "controller" in PHP that checks the URL for it's parts, and finds the right content based on one part etc. the URL doesn't have to point to an actual file, what is served, is up to you.

Comment: Got it .. Thank you @adeneo And Vohuman .. upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can define many rules about rewriting the url address in apache `.htaccess` file. There magic happens.

You can look in more detail how to define rewrite rules in `.htaccess` [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#rewrite).