# How can I check the post slug?

Tags: php, regex, url

**Scenario:** As you know, StackOverflow checks the title in the question. I mean when you open this URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839016/should-i-store-the-result-of-an-function
```

automatically it will be replaced with this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839016/should-i-store-the-result-of-an-function-into-an-array
```

That replacement is because of being incomplete the first URL.

---

Ok well, I'm trying to make such a system by PHP. Here is **my attempt**:

```
// getting this from the URL
$id = '38839016';

// fetching this from database based on that id (38839016)
$real_title = $result['title'];
//=> Should I store the result of an function into an array
$real_title = str_replace("-"," ",strtolower($real_title));
//=> should-i-store-the-result-of-an-function-into-an-array

// getting whole uri                                
$current_uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
//=> /questions/38839016/should-i-store-the-result-of-an-function
```

---

**What I want to do:** I need to compare `$real_title` with *title-part of the `$current_uri`*. How can I determine *"title-part"*? It is everything which is after `$id.'/'` until `/` or `?` or `$` *(end of string)*. How can I do that comparison?

And then:

```
if ( preg_match("//", $current_uri) ) {
    // all fine. continue loading the page
    continue;
} else {
    // replace title-part of the $current_uri with $real_title       
    preg_replace("//", $real_title, $current_uri);         

    // redirect to this post with correct slug
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].);
}
```

briefly, I want to complete these:

```
if ( preg_match("//", $current_uri) ) {

preg_replace("//", $real_title, $current_uri);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in simple words, there is a good url and a requested url

if the requested url not equal the good url

redirect the visitor to the good one

```
<?
$id = '38839016';
$good_url = '/questions/'.$id.'/'.str_replace("-"," ",strtolower($result['title']));

preg_match( '/\/[0-9]+\/([a-z0-9-]+)\/.*/', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], $matches);
if ($matches[1] != str_replace("-"," ",strtolower($result['title'])))
header('Location: '.$good_url);
```

Comment: This solution fails if there is some passed-parameters as GET method, like this: `?arg1=value1&arg2=value2`

Comment: @MartinAJ Sorry, I added this answer because you add the stackoverflow example

Comment: Are you want to correct only the slug in the url without modifying any other syntax in the url ?

Comment: Ok, I'm searching now about the solution

Comment: Well your approach seems correct, because `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` doesn't get parameters

Comment: I've changed the answer

Comment: Check the current answer, it may be more than helpful